# Having issue selecting rows by the same count

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a following table:

[image]

The following conditions should be met:

1. The selection is primarily done by `sender_id = 9`. This one is a main constraint.
2. The value of `receiver_id` must never match `sender_id` column. Only those rows should be selected.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    receiver_id 
FROM 
    users_messages 
GROUP BY 
    receiver_id ,
    sender_id
HAVING 
    COUNT(receiver_id) = COUNT(sender_id) AND sender_id = 9 AND receiver_id != 9
```

And by this, I'm expecting the output only to be `10`. But the problem is, that it also selects `2` which is breaking the second condition stated above.

What's wrong with this query?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
select um.*
from user_messages um
where rm.sender = 9 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from user_messages um2
                  where um2.sender = um.receiver
                 );
```

If you just want the receivers, you can -- of course -- use `select distinct um.receiver`.

Comment: This is exactly it. But since your answer suggests a sub-query, wouldn't it be really becoming slower and slower when data starts growing?

Comment: make sure that `[not]exists` runs fast mostly @Yang

Comment: @Yang . . . If performance is an issue, then you want an index on `user_messages(sender, receiver)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a left self join and return the unmatched rows:

```
select distinct u1.receiver_id
from users_messages u1 left join users_messages u2
on u2.sender_id = u1.receiver_id and u2.receiver_id = u1.sender_id
where u1.sender_id = 9 and u2.id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Most simple, fast and logical solution

```
SELECT * FROM `some` 
WHERE sender_id = 9 AND receiver_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sender_id FROM some)
```